Is it possible to overwrite an existing logicalType conversion via the avro-maven-plugin?
Say I want to provide a custom converter to translate logicalType "timestamp-millis" to default to ZonedDateTime in the generated Java class instead of an Instant. Is this possible?
I tried the properties customConversions and customLogicalTypeFactories in the pom.xml but those are not what I'm looking for. It seems like customConversions is for custom logical types, not overwriting existing ones, so when I put my custom converter class it does nothing.
I do not control the 'logicalType' field from the schema so there's no way for me to redefine the types on the avro schema itself.
